# Bootstrap Modal Scrolldown

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap modal and want to scroll down on button click:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal"
    data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" data-dismiss="modal">
                <i class="fa fa-times"></i><span class="hidden-xs">Close</span></button>
            <button id="refresh" type="button" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">
                <i class="fa fa-refresh"></i><span class="hidden-xs"> Refresh</span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title"> myTitle</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <p id="verylongtext">Here is a very long text</p>
            <p class="hidden" id="modal-bottom"></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$('#refresh').click(function() {
$("#modal-dialog").animate({
        scrollTop: $("#modal-bottom").offset().top
    }, 1000);
});
```

This is my [bootply](http://www.bootply.com/loZ7L22oeG) so far. I tried several different ways but i don't get it working.

EDIT: I updated the snippet and bootply, but it still doesn't work...

Comment: Please include the code from your Fiddle. Fiddles can expire, which means your question becomes useless to future users should that happen. Even better: build it using the snippet tools here on SO! :D Also, that's not a fiddle, that's a Bootply.

Comment: Oh ok i didn't knew that. I'll edit it. Sorry :)

Comment: No worries, happens more often than you'd think. :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to put an extra container element within modal-body:

```
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" data-dismiss="modal">
                <i class="fa fa-times"></i><span class="hidden-xs"> Close</span></button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" data-bind="click: refresh">
                <i class="fa fa-refresh"></i><span class="hidden-xs"> Refresh</span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" data-bind="text: title"></h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div id="scrollContainer">
                <p id="topAnchor"></p>
                <pre data-bind="text: content"></pre>
                <p id="bottomAnchor"></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The `refresh`-function does this:

```
$("#scrollContainer").animate({ scrollTop: $("#topAnchor").offset().top}, 0);
    // some other stuff here...
$("#scrollContainer").animate({ scrollTop: $("#bottomAnchor").offset().top}, 500);
```

The animation is always from top to down this way. If only the scrolling to `#bottomAnchor` was called, the animation would jump up again from the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

So I played around with it, and you're missing stuff from the initial div for your modal header. I figured this out by copying the markup for a modal from the Bootstrap documentation and using your button to open it, which allowed the modal to scroll smoothly. I replaced the first line because I noticed items were missing, and that's the problem. The order the items is in might also be important, as I added them in various spots but still couldn't get it to work.

Make this the first line of your modal:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
```

Here it is running in a **[Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/SzpMPKhUoJ)**.

Comment: The initial stuff is in my durandal.js Module, so i just copied it for demonstration purposes. I guess the problem is in the jquery command.